# Handle volume button when Option Menu is visible

Tags: android, button, volume, optionmenu

From my activity, I correctly handled the opening on OptionMenu with this code :

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    if(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP == event.getKeyCode() || KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN == event.getKeyCode()){
        openOptionsMenu();
        return true;
  }else
      return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

But when the Option Menu is visible, I cannot intercept the KyDown anymore. My intend is to be able to close the Option Menu the same way I open it, with volume button.

Any suggestion ?